# imagemagick (or other) png->svg->png or svg->png

Tags: image, imagemagick

Im trying to convert either a svg to png or png to svg back to png with imagemagick and it seems like everything I try the final image is black outlined. I'm expecting it to keep all colors the same through-out the process but it doesn't seem to?

```
convert input.svg output.png
```

Even if I try the autotrace approach on the imagemagick site nothing changes. I'd prefer to just be able to have the input be PNG output to SVG (smooth borders) and then back out to PNG. Might sound silly but all of the smooth-bordering/anti-aliasing approaches mentioned on the imagemagick site seem to make all output (any colors but white) be black?

Comment: Please provide a simple input image, the command you run and the output image you get and a description of what you expected.

Comment: Transcoding a [raster graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) to [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) is not an easy task. Can you provide examples & reduce this question to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?